# Hourly prize instant giveaway algorithm

Tags: random, probability

I've been asked to build a prize giveaway web page with the following competition parameters:

- A user can only enter the competition once per day
- It's an instant win competition, the user will know if they have won or not when they enter
- We want to give away on average 1 prize per hour

My first thought was at the start of each hour, to select a random second within that hour for the prize to be given away. The first user who enters after that second is the winner. If a hour goes past where no one actually enters, a new time will be chosen somewhere in the next 12 hours to give away that hours prize (this is to stop the late night prizes all being given away in the morning).

I can't tell if this will be random enough for a fair competition. Also, there is a slight security risk in that if someone were to view the upcoming prize draw database record, they could enter at the right time and win the prize.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Randomness is difficult to prove, so its definitely random enough

Comment: Some contests use "the xth client wins"

Comment: The simplest solution would be divide your daily traffic by 24 and award a prize every xth person where x is that value.

Comment: Problem is the 'instant win' part of the competition. We don't know the daily traffic to the site, so if there is a surge in entries all the winners will be in the first part of the day.

Comment: And why is that a problem?  As long as people don't know that there are no more prized being given away they will stil come and just believe they are unlucky

Comment: Off-topic, but your definition of randomness here's a bit vague, if this is just a programming class and not a maths class I wouldn't bother trying to prove anything.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus True, I'd like to see if there are other options though. If word got around that there is a higher chance of winning in the morning then it may break the competition.

Comment: @simonzack Not for a class, this is for a real world client!

Comment: @Ryano best option then is to randomly pick a time, if there's no winner for that time, then move the prize to a busier timeslot.