# Even prize distribution

Tags: algorithm, random, probability

I'm currently facing interesting algorithm problem and I am looking for ideas or possible solutions. Topic seems to be common so maybe it's known and solved but I'm unable to find it.

So lets assume that I'm running shop and
I'm making `lottery` for buying customers. Each time they buy something they can win prize.

- Prizes are given to customers instantly after buying.
- I have `X prizes` and
- I will be running lottery for `Y days`
- Paying customer (act of buying, transaction) should have `equal chance to win` prize
- Prizes should be distributed till last day (at last day there should be left some prizes to distribute)
- There can not be `left` prizes at the end
- I do **not** have historical data of transactions per day (no data from before lottery) to estimate average number of transactions (yet lottery could change number of transactions)
- I can gather data while lottery is running

It this is not-solvable, what is closest solution?
Instant prize distribution have to stay.

Comment: There should be some prizes last day but no left prizes 1 second before end of lottery

Comment: Then all you need to do is pretend you have only X-1 prizes (or X-k prizes, if you want to keep k prizes for the last day) and Y-1 days.  This leaves 1 (or k) prizes over for the last day.

Comment: Yea, but it does not solve the whole problem

Comment: For the rest, you can use [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Comment: @j_random_hacker if i understand correctly *Reservoir sampling* i can not grant prize instantly after transaction

Comment: Nothing will guarantee that you're not left with a lot of prizes (if nobody comes into your shop the last few days of the lottery) or that the people coming into the shop at the last moment still have a chance (at some point someone's going to win the last prize, but people could still come into the shop after that.)

Comment: @KrzysztofBogdan: You're right, using reservoir sampling would imply taking prizes *away from* people you had already given them too!  But I think m69's comment is right: I see no way to handle every possible situation without contradictions emerging.

Comment: since any lottery is a game of chance you cannot make any definitive predictions all the way to the last day, especially when you have unknown number of people coming in. Distribution of them coming in during the period of interest. You can only approximate but never be sure.

Comment: @AlPimenov and m64 You are totally right. I am looking for algorithm that will be closest to those requirements. What we can do is to manipulate chance to win prize, yet trying to be most "fair"

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826287/hourly-prize-instant-giveaway-algorithm?rq=1

Comment: @m69 Similar problem but not much insights

Comment: @KrzysztofBogdan Doesn't the idea of dividing the time into X parts, selecting a random moment in each part to hand out a prize, and giving it to the first client who comes in after the chosen time, answer most of your requirements (except the people who come in at the very end no longer having a chance) in a very simple way?

Comment: @m69 It is acceptable solution but it have one downside: Lets say that there is no crowd in shop in the morning (higher chances to win) and it is  crowded afternoon (lower changes to win). Sorin algorithm solves this problem better.

Answer (score 2):

## Possible Solution #1

Based on @m69 comment
[image: Randomly selected events in time]

Lets says there are 6 prizes (total prizes) and 2 days of lottery.
Lets define Prizes By Day as PBD (to satisfy requirement have prizes till last day). 
PBD = total prizes / days
We randomly choose as many as PBD events every day. **Every transaction after this event is winning transaction.** 
Can be optimized to no to use last hour of last day of lottery to guarantee giving away all of prizes.

### Pluses

Random. Simple, elegant solution.

### Minuses

Seems that users have no equal chance to win.

## Possible Solution #2

Based on @Sorin answer

[image: Solution based on analyzing last time frame]

We start to analyze first time frame (example 1 hour). And we calculate chance to win as:
[image]
where:
Δprizes = left prizes,
Δframes = left frames

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is impossible. Once you've gave away the last prize you can't prove any guarantee for the number of customers left, so not all customers will have equal chance to win a prize.

You can do something that approximates it fairly well. You can try to estimate the number of customers you will have, assume that they are evenly distributed and then spread the prizes over the period while the contest is running. This will give you a ratio that you can use to say if a given customer is a winner. Then as the contest progresses, change the estimates to match what you see, and what prizes are left. Run this update every x (hours/ minutes or even customer transaction) to make sure the rate isn't too low and every q prizes to make sure the rate isn't too high. Don't run the update too often if the prizes are given away or the algorithm might react too strongly if there's a period with low traffic (say overnight).

Let me give you an example. Say you figure out that you're going to see 100 customers per hour and you should give prizes every 200 customers. So roughly 1 every 2 hours. After 3 hours you come back and you see you saw 300 customers per hour and you've given out 4 prizes already. So you can now adjust the expectation to 300 customers per hour and adjust the distribution rate to match what is left.

This will work even if your initial is too low or too high.
This will break badly if your estimate is too far AND you updates are far in between (say you only check after a day but you've already given away all the prizes).

This can leave prizes on the table. If you don't want that you can reduce the amount of time the program considers the contest as running so that it should finish the prizes before the end of the contest. You can limit the number of prizes awarded in a given day to make the distribution more uniform (don't set it to `X/Y`, but something like `X/Y * .25` so that there's some variation), and update the limit at the end of the day to account for variation in awards given.

Comment: That is one of my ideas, adjusting chance to win based on last frame of time.